# Determine activity type (completed) on Lead object

Tags: trigger, leads, activities

I have a custom field on task and event called Type with values as Call, Voicemail, Email..

I have a custom field on lead object, called last activity type. Now I want to populate this field on the lead detail page. Is there any standard way to do this.

Thoughts? Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: trigger is the fastest answer but i would prefer thinking to find have i missed anything else .Since task or event not master detail so cross object formula field wont apply.

Comment: A simple trigger would be the best way to accomplish this.  I know you asked about a standard way, which I dont know if there is.  I can post some code for the trigger if you are willing to try it with a trigger.

Comment: Yes, can you please post some code. Meanwhile I am also looking for a standard way.

Comment: Added some code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something Like this should work.

```
trigger ExampleTrigger on Task (after insert) {

    set<Id> leadIds = new  set<Id>();
    for(Task t: trigger.new){
        if(t.Who.Type == 'Lead'){
            leadIds.add(t.WhoId);
        }
    }
    list<Lead> leadsToUpdate = new list<Lead>([Select Id, Name, Last_Activity_Type, (Select Id, ActivityDate, Type__c From Tasks) From Lead Where Id in : leadIds]);

    //This will cycyle through all the leads
    for(Lead l: leadsToUpdate){
        Date latestActivity;

            /*This will go through each task related to the current lead and find the 
            task with the latest date, and change the Last_Activity_Date__c fieild
            on that lead to the type of that latest activity*/

            for(Task t : l.Tasks){
            if (latestActivity == null || lastestActivity < t.ActivityDate){
                latestActivity = t.ActivityDate;
                l.Last_Activity_Type__c = t.Type__c;
            }
        }
    }

    update leadsToUpdate;

}
```